# How can i create an object class to perform downloading of .jar dependencies from maven repository

Tags: java, dependency-injection, executable-jar, maven-assembly-plugin

According to the title above, i need help on How to create an object class to perform downloading of **.jar** dependencies from maven repository. I have a JAR file that contains three classes which include: **CommandHandler.class**; **KeyStroke.class** and **Main.class** and each of the classes has it dependencies that need to be download free Maven repository. Now, my question is how can i create an object to perform all the necessary task needed to download dependencies before my main program logic start execution. Because i believe without the dependencies my above classes implementation might run into severe Exceptions... Please any help/suggestion/tips will be highly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: I see you have less awareness about how maven works. Once you define the dependencies in the POM file and install, all the necessary jars/dependencies are downloaded automatically from the repositories. https://maven.apache.org/run-maven/

Comment: @Vaibs please note that am not creating maven project, my project is in javaFX, so all i need is an object to perform all the download dependencies (programmatically).

Comment: Thanks for correcting us. Please denote the same in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dynamic load a jar at run-time,you can do following operation.In the following example,i assume the dependent jar is `spring-context`,like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and i get the url of that jar,`http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.1.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar?spm=0.0.0.0.kG1Pdw&file=spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar`.

Then,there is a class `Target` is depends on the class `DateFormatter` which is included in the `spring-context`,and has a method be named `start`.

```
import org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatter;

public class Target {

private static DateFormatter dateFormatter;

public void start(){
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    dateFormatter=new DateFormatter();
    System.out.println(dateFormatter);
    }
}
```

The next,we compile and package above code as a jar named `target.jar`,which is stored at `D:\\test\\target.jar`.

And next,we should declare a class as `BootStrap` in another jar that will call the method `start` of `Target` instance.The `BootStarp` class will dynamic load the `target.jar` and `spring-context` jar files by same `classloader` which is a `URLClassLoader` instance,because of this,the method `start` in `Target` instance can access the `DateFormatter` class that be defined in `spring-context`.

```
public class BootStrap {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    URL url = new URL("http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.1.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar?spm=0.0.0.0.kG1Pdw&file=spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar");
    URL url2= (new File("D:\\test\\target.jar").toURI().toURL());
    URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url,url2});
    Class<?> clz = classLoader.loadClass("com.zhuyiren.Target");
    Object main = clz.newInstance();
    Method test = clz.getMethod("start");
    test.invoke(main);
    }
}
```

The finally,run the `BootStrap` main method.There are two important thing:

1. The `BootStrap` class and `Target` class don't belong to a same jar file.
2. The `target.jar` is not stored in `CLASSPATH` path.

And we can see the result:

```
java.net.URLClassLoader@e9e54c2
org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatter@4dd8dc3
```

That menas we access the `DateFormatter` instance which is defined in `spring-context` jar file successfully,and the `spring-context` is not stored in `CLASSPATH`,even not stored a local file system.

Comment: thanks for the code it really helps! but what if my dependencies are not in **sping-context**

Comment: @Divverest That is a example,you can add your dependencies jar file into the `UrlClassLoader` instance when it construct,like `New UrlClassLoader(new Url[]{a,b,c})`.The a,b,c is the URL of the jar file.

Comment: thanks once again! u have just Answered my question, really appreciate.

Comment: @Divverest If resolve your question,you can accept and upvote my answer.